# 2 large text files, find the lines that are not duplicate linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, compare, duplicates

Hello fellow stackoverflowers,

I am looking to find lines that are not duplicate, example;

Text file 1:

```
cats 3
dogs 8
mice 4
pigs 10
...
```

Text file 2:

```
dogs 8
mice 4
cats 78
pigs 29
bird 6
...
```

Both files have dogs 8 and mice 4.

The output of different lines would be:

```
cats 78
pigs 29
bird 6
```

To clarify 'cats 3' got changed to 'cats 78' and 'pigs 10' got changed to 'pigs 29'.

I was hopefully looking for a way this could be done in linux terminal like;
command input1.txt input2.txt diffrences.txt

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What happened to `cats 3` and `pigs 10`? Your question is incomplete unless you cover all the bases.  Also, what have you tried.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].  You are expected to try your own solution first and post what you've done. Finally, since you're asking about Linux command line usage, this is off-topic and belongs on [su].

Comment: 'cats 3' got changed to 'cats 78' and 'pigs 10' got changed to 'pigs 29'